# How to generate images with the same seed but with different kind of noise schedulers using Diffusers

Tags: deep-learning, stable-diffusion, diffusers

I'm trying to use the Diffusers library to generate images with different schedulers (Just generate images I don't want to have to prompt).
For this I follow this tutorial: https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/using-diffusers/write_own_pipeline.
As well as: https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/using-diffusers/schedulers.

Here is the code:

```
import torch
from diffusers import DDPMScheduler, EulerAncestralDiscreteScheduler, EulerDiscreteScheduler, UNet2DModel
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
```

I first defined my schedulers and the model, according to the tutorial:

```
schedulers = [DDPMScheduler.from_pretrained("google/ddpm-cat-256"), EulerAncestralDiscreteScheduler.from_pretrained("google/ddpm-cat-256"), EulerDiscreteScheduler.from_pretrained("google/ddpm-cat-256")]

model = UNet2DModel.from_pretrained("google/ddpm-cat-256", use_safetensors=True)
```

Setting timesteps to 50 for every scheduler:

```
for scheduler in schedulers:
    scheduler.set_timesteps(50)
```

Getting the initial noise:

```
sample_size = model.config.sample_size
noise = torch.randn((1, 3, sample_size, sample_size))
```

Denoising the initial noise for each scheduler:

```
denoised_dict = {}
input = noise

for i, scheduler in enumerate(schedulers):
    denoised_dict[i] = []
    
    for t in scheduler.timesteps:
        with torch.no_grad():
            noisy_residual = model(input, t).sample
        previous_noisy_sample = scheduler.step(scheduler.scale_model_input(noisy_residual, t), t, input).prev_sample
        input = previous_noisy_sample
        
    denoised_dict[i] = input
```

Plotting a resulting image:

```
image = (denoised_dict[0] / 2 + 0.5).clamp(0, 1).squeeze()
image = (image.permute(1, 2, 0) * 255).round().to(torch.uint8).cpu().numpy()
image = Image.fromarray(image)
image
```

The problem is that images generated using EulerDiscreteScheduler and EulerAncestralDiscreteScheduler are just noise, meaningless, not even displayed, etc.

I tried several ways, including using only EulerAncestralDiscreteScheduler and following exactly the tutorial. I got a message:
`The` scale_model_input`function should be called before`step`to ensure correct denoising. See`StableDiffusionPipeline `for a usage example.`

I also called EulerAncestralDiscreteScheduler as suggested in this tutorial: https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/using-diffusers/schedulers:

```
scheduler = DDPMScheduler.from_pretrained("google/ddpm-cat-256")

scheduler = EulerAncestralDiscreteScheduler.from_config(scheduler.config)
```

Anyway, nothing works and no matter how many times I read the tutorials, I just can't do it.

Anyone could help me out of this situation?